# How port can close when Im close the program

Tags: java, sockets, socket.io, port, socketexception

I dont want to change port number , but I receive an exception "Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind"

ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1234, 180);

Comment: how do you close the program? The exception tell you the port is already in use.

Comment: Call `close()` on the server socket before ending the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have another process bound to the same port.

If you are using Windows then open CMD and run this command

netstat -aon | findstr 1234

you will get the process ID which you can find in task manager which is using that particular port. i.e 1234 in your case